# Changed object path and Dirty stages for nested objects in Vue state

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Let's say I have an object contains some array of objects in some of its properties.
Whenever I make changes in some fields whether it's a field in object in array or the root object, I want to define that object "dirty: true" with a code like this: `object.defineProperty(path, '_dirty', true)`.

```
{
    "id": "48e143e5-eda0-490a-a87a-dbef128f539e",
    "parentId": null,
    "groups": [
        {
            "id": "142c7263-26ab-4169-88bb-5b2b880f3b97",
            "overviewId": "48e143e5-eda0-490a-a87a-dbef128f539e",
            "parts": [
                {
                    "id": "730adbca-20c0-427a-8228-7000d0553466",
                    "overviewGroupId": "142c7263-26ab-4169-88bb-5b2b880f3b97",
                },
                {
                    "id": "9c749aa0-b1c0-49cd-81c1-272d9bfe5df7",
                    "overviewGroupId": "142c7263-26ab-4169-88bb-5b2b880f3b97",
                }
            ],
        }
    ],
    "templateInfo": {
        "id": "34d2be1c-9b4e-4eb2-b452-82c7929057c8",
        "name": "Standart OV",
        "parentId": null,
        "typeId": 0,
        "storeId": "ee7bdc31-8c13-4111-9225-cb780b46e1a1"
    },
    "pageTypeInfo": {
        "id": "016ef17a-4cd7-4096-b387-6b16c39df41e",
        "typeId": 3,
        "code": "code A",
    }
}
```

I am storing this object in data like this:

```
data() {
    return {
        source: {},
    }
},
```

and have a watcher:

```
source: {
    handler(newValue, oldValue){
        console.log(...arguments)
    },
    deep: true
}
```

Is it possible to have the changed path like "groups[0].parts[1].id" and make the _dirty true for targeted object which in the path when change occurs?

Comment: Hello @halilcakar. TLDR; trying to make a CRUD base.

want to create a generic getter setter with isDirty, isFresh flags for the main data object that requires CRUD operations. By using dirty flags I thought I can understand if the object need to update, create or do-nothing operations. Have a look at https://github.com/sindresorhus/on-change this package and how they grabbing the path of changed target. I want to adapt this to Vue

Comment: deep watcher's `(newValue, oldValue)` will return the same object since objects are shared by reference. That is, unless you reassign the entire object each time you make a change. I assume you don't do that, you'd probably just want to change a single property in the same `source` object. Then its not possible to watch for changes in it except building your own watcher function or using the one you linked in your comment. I'd like to ask what's the issue in using the watcher that's you've linked?

Comment: A solution would be to clone the old `source` object into another data object each time you make a change to this `source` object, but then I'd argue its easier to just add the `_dirty` each time you make a change to the `source` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method that updates the value using the `$set` function like so:

```js
update(root, key, value) {
  this.$set(root, key, value);
  this.$set(root[key], '__dirty', true); 
}
```